MODIS LST tiles concatenation or merging issue with xarray
I am having an issue while concatenating two xarray data files. The two files (MODIS LST, accessed through the STAC API) are from the same date/time but correspond to adjacent geographical tiles (side-by-side, by longitude or x). When I use the xr.concat() function, everything works fine without any errors, but when I visualize the data, I notice many vertical white lines, figure below (which appear to be no-data values). When I plot the individual files (from the same time step), the data exists in the regions where the vertical lines appear (these figures not shown here).
A reproducible example is provided below if anyone would like to give it a try:
import pystac_client
import stackstac
import planetary_computer
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

catalog = pystac_client.Client.open(
    "https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/api/stac/v1",
    modifier=planetary_computer.sign_inplace,
)

# time range
time_range = "2000-10-01/2000-10-30"

# tile 1
bbox = [75, 30, 80, 32]
search = catalog.search(collections=["modis-11A2-061"], bbox=bbox, datetime=time_range)
items = search.get_all_items()
ds_d_t1 = stackstac.stack(items, epsg=4326, chunksize='auto', assets=["LST_Day_1km"], properties=False)
ds_d_t1 = ds_d_t1.rename("LST")

# tile 1
bbox = [66, 35, 67, 37]
search = catalog.search(collections=["modis-11A2-061"], bbox=bbox, datetime=time_range)
items = search.get_all_items()
ds_d_t2 = stackstac.stack(items, epsg=4326, chunksize='auto', assets=["LST_Day_1km"], properties=False)
ds_d_t2 = ds_d_t2.rename("LST")

# lets handle the time, because there is no proper time coordinate
# extract year and day of the year from MODIS ID
def get_date(modis_id):
    year = int(modis_id.split('.')[1][1:5])
    day_of_year = int(modis_id.split('.')[1][5:])
    date = pd.to_datetime(str(year) + str(day_of_year), format='%Y%j')
    return date

# create a new time coordinate variable using the get_date function
ds_d_t1['time'] = xr.DataArray([get_date(modis_id) for modis_id in ds_d_t1['id'].values], 
                               dims='time', coords={'time': ds_d_t1['time']})

ds_d_t2['time'] = xr.DataArray([get_date(modis_id) for modis_id in ds_d_t2['id'].values],
                          dims='time', coords={'time': ds_d_t2['time']})

ds_d_t1 = ds_d_t1.sortby('time')
ds_d_t2 = ds_d_t2.sortby('time')

# concat
ds_m = xr.concat([ds_d_t1, ds_d_t2], dim="x")
ds_m = ds_m.sortby('x')

# visualise
ds_m[0].plot()

Here is the output figure, with many vertical white lines:

Any help in concatenating these files properly would be greatly appreciated.

So you want to stack two tiles next to each other. I think, concat is not the tool you should use here. Consider combine_by_coords instead

I tried with combine_by_coords but no success. The white lines appear at the intersection points (roughly 69.5 to 77.5 on x/long direction) between two parallelogram shape/type of MODIS LST tiles.

The issue is that, without access to the API, it's hard to run your code... Could you provide a smaller working example that does not depend on this API? Also, are you sure that there are no actual holes in your data?

This seems related to the fact that the x-coords values are not the same in the two tiles, for values that "correspond" to each other because they are very close. One can verify that by inspecting (after running your code):
xmin = 69.270598
ds_d_t1[0].x[ds_d_t1[0].x > xmin].values
ds_d_t2[0].x[ds_d_t2[0].x > xmin].values

and noticing that the mesh coords are not the same.
If xarray merging fails (I couldn't find a good recipe to make it work properly), a workaround for plotting could be dealing with the isolated tiles one by one:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot the first dataset with a single colorbar
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ds_d_t1[0].plot(add_colorbar=False)
ds_d_t2[0].plot()

# extend plot to entire boundaries
min_x, max_x = ds_m.x.min().values, ds_m.x.max().values
min_y, max_y = ds_m.y.min().values, ds_m.y.max().values

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([min_x, max_x])
ax.set_ylim([min_y, max_y])

# Add labels and legend
plt.title("Combined")
plt.show()

which at least should allow you to avoid the artifacts that you saw:


Hi @Davide, thank you for working with my data and problem.
yes, I understand the concern. Plotting them together looks fine.
However, for other operation (spatial mean, clipping, etc) I need to have them merged, do you have any solution for merging/combining them as data.array so that I can work further in xarray?

Hey sorry, I didn't manage to make a solution based on combine_by_coords work :(
